# Notify only one Repository in a multiple SCM setup

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control

I am learning Jenkins and trying to use StashNotifier to notify the Stash repo `A` the build status, i.e. `SUCCESS` or `FAILED`. Since the repo `A` depends on repo `B` and repo `C`, I used the following code to get repo `B` and `C` also into the build workspace.

```
checkout resolveScm(source: [$class: 'GitSCMSource', remote: "ssh://git@stash.org:8888/group/repo_B.git",
                                   credentialsId: '...omitted...', includes: '*', excludes: '',
                                   extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', parentCredentials: true, recursiveSubmodules: true]]],
                          targets: [BRANCH_NAME, "${java.net.URLEncoder.encode(env.BRANCH_NAME, "UTF-8")}"])

checkout resolveScm(source: [$class: 'GitSCMSource', remote: "ssh://git@stash.org:8888/group/repo_C.git",
                                   credentialsId: '...omitted...', includes: '*', excludes: '',
                                   extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', parentCredentials: true, recursiveSubmodules: true]]],
                          targets: [BRANCH_NAME, "${java.net.URLEncoder.encode(env.BRANCH_NAME, "UTF-8")}"])
```

The StashNotifier is configured like:

```
step([$class: 'StashNotifier'])
```

However, after the build, all three repos are notified. Is it possible to only notify the repo `A` and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/stashnotifier-plugin/blob/d98ab25f54e30b27c17bed7b0c99eb11191fc8f5/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/stashNotifier/StashNotifier.java#L369-L415) of StashNotifier, if no `commitSha1` is given when using StashNotifier, all commits will be gathered and therefore all repositories will be notified. As long as `commitSha1` is specified, only the specified repo will be notified.

First, get the commit hash using

```
checkout scm
env.GIT_COMMIT = sh(script: "git rev-parse HEAD", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

And later in the pipeline, notify stash by

```
step([$class: 'StashNotifier',
      commitSha1: "${env.GIT_COMMIT}"])
```